# Question on convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

If I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ that is convex in ${\bf x} = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and strictly convex in one of the variables, say $x_1$, then is $f({\bf x})$ strictly convex in ${\bf x}$? If so, how would I prove this?

Comment: What does 'weakly' convex mean in this context?

Comment: Edited, I meant convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any convex (but not strictly convex) function $c:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and any strictly convex function $s:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = c(x)+s(y)$ satisfies the criteria in the question, but clearly $f$ is not strictly convex for any fixed $y$.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a similar question a while ago, care to explain the difference between this case and the one seen here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720680/is-this-function-strictly-convex I'm a bit confused.

Comment: If I get a chance I will have a look at it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'explain the difference'? There are many differences...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I don't understand what additional property of the function (in the link) is making it strictly convex compared to only convexity of the function in the question posed here. If I were to add an additional assumption to the question above to make $f$ strictly convex, what would it be? Is it because each function in the sum of the three terms (in the link) is convex in the same variable that the function is strictly convex in (i.e. $x_1$)? Relating it back to this post, being convex in ${\bf x}$ and strictly convex in one variable is not enough. Thanks for your attention

Comment: I added an answer to the other question. Hopefully that helps answer your question. Note that if the function $c$ above was strictly convex, then  $f$ would be too.

Answer (score 1):

No, just consider $f(x) = x_1^2$. This is strictly convex in $x_1$ and weakly convex in $x$ but not strictly convex in $x$.

Comment: Wouldn't $f$ then be a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? I would like to place the additional restriction that each $x_i$ needs to show up in the function.

Comment: isn't $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)<\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda\in(0,1)$? Meaning that $f$ is strictly convex.